# How to fix file handling output issue, I am getting the same output printed twice

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm working with files in python. I am trying to read from a file that i have currently written to. While reading the file, output is getting printed twice.

```
myfile = open('example_file.txt','w')

myfile.write('why is this getting printed twice')

myfile.close()


myfile = open('example_file.txt')

print(myfile.read())

myfile.close()
```

I expect the output to be 
why is this getting printed twice

but the actual output is
why is this getting printed twice
why is this getting printed twice

Comment: Attempted to repro the bug with an empty text file and got the correct output.

Comment: Not sure why this would be, but is it possible that the code is executing twice?

Comment: This code give one time output as expected.

Comment: It only prints it once for me, too. As expected. What OS and version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.0 and windows 10 OS. 
The code is executing only once I have checked